# Tkinter - Configuring a Label

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a maze game that's based on arrays.
I have it so when the player(Value 1) reaches the end point (Value -5), my label changes from Level 1, to Level 2.

I'm having problems implementing the level feature. I was wondering if anyone can help me.
I believe I'm suppose to be using "configure", but it's not working out for me.

I have level as a global variable.
When the player reaches the end, it adjusts the level = 2, then recalls init(canvas)

Comment: To make sure I understand, you want to change the text in a label?

Comment: yes that's correct, i'd like to change "Level 1" to "Level 2" and so forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Tkinter stringVar to link with the label like this

```
current_level = Tkinter.StringVar()
Tkinter.Label(master, textvariable=current_level)
```

Then to change the text in the label use

```
current_level.set('Level 2')
```

etc.

Comment: You can also use configure to change the text. `labelname.configure(text="Level 2")`

Comment: I tried doing somethign similar to that, but it just keeps printing a different label, I guess i didn't put them in the correct places. Thanks, will try again

Comment: hey, do you know where I would add this?

Comment: You have to create the stringVar before you create the label, if it needs to be a global variable (like level), then it could be defined at the same time. (I am not recommending the use of global variables. You set the stringvar to a new value in the code where you initialize the Label text on creation and then again where you change the label text to 'Label 2' etc.

Comment: To stop adding new labels you need to keep the label widget in a variable when it is created, the use that variable to configure the new label text.
label_id.configure(text='Level 2')
Again this would need to be a global variable unless you pass it as a parameter to moveMaze.